# criar objetos em loop

Tags: r

Preciso fazer diversos aggregate .

por exemplo:

```
2012ocup10 <- aggregate(PNAD2012[c("peso_pes")], by=PNAD2012["klems"],
                       FUN=sum,na.rm=T)
```

mas preciso realizar o mesmo procedimento para `PNAD2011,PNAD2010,`...

Eu utilizo loop desta forma :

```
for(ano in (1995:2012)[-c(6,16)]){   
  tabela.p <- apply(get(paste0("PNAD",ano))[c( "idade", "anos_est", "rend_prin", 
                                               "rend_tot",
                                               "horas", "horas_s")],
                    2,FUN=mean,na.rm=T) 
}
```

Quando adapto pro aggregate não consigo fazer ele criar multiplas tabelas `(2012ocup10,2011ocup10,...)`.Utilizando get(paste0...) me parece que não acessa as variáveis dentro do `data.frame`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ennio, você não pode criar nomes de objetos que comecem com um número. `2012ocup10` não é um nome válido para um objeto do R. Você tem que ao menos colocar uma letra ou algo do tipo antes neste nome, por exemplo, `pnad2012ocup10`.

Feita esta ressalva, um código como o seguinte deveria funcionar:

```
for (ano in (1995:2012)){
  assign(paste0("pnad", ano, "ocup10"),
         aggregate(get(paste0("PNAD", ano))["peso_pes"], 
                   by=get(paste0("PNAD", ano))["klems"],
                   FUN=sum,na.rm=T))
}
```

Comment: Muito obrigado ,ajudou MUITO ! Não tinha pensado em utilizar assign ,e nem atentado ao número na criação do objeto